# Can't get Strict PHP error to display

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a theme in WordPress and a friend was installing it when he got the message

```
Strict standards: Declaration of Walker_Nav_Primary::start_lvl() should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl(&$output,$depth = 0, $args = Array) in .../inc/walker.php on line 0
```

but for some reason I do not see the message on my set-up I have PHP display error on and added this code to my header.php file

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
```

but still nothing, I've never seen an error with the line number as 0.
What does this error mean and how can I get it to display?

Comment: Have you verified that you're both on the same PHP version?

Comment: What version of PHP Are you running?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything. Most likely you have turned `display_errors` **off**, but expect a _plethora_ I wish I could be there to see the result of turning `display_errors` on

Comment: @Jordy Yes same PHP.

Comment: @riggsfolly Yes same PHP, error reporting on and it shows other errors just not this one.

Comment: did you look in the PHP error log

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, can't see it there.

Comment: See my first comment! What version of PHP are you running

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes we are both running the same PHP v5.5.12

Comment: What do you have set for `error_reporting` & `display_errors` & `log_errors` in `php.ini`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have E_ALL / On / On